# Trying to create buttons over an image

Tags: html, javascript-objects

I am attempting to create a simple calculator and having difficulty figuring out if I can use eventlisteners on map>area elements over an image.. or if I need to use button or a and use the coordinates or how I would go about making the areas of the image of this calculator clickable buttons that I can make do things in js. Sorry if this question is a little convoluted, my brain is a bit swimmy at the moment.

Comment: why do you want to use an image in the first place? wouldnt it be easier to just create a grid?

Comment: It'd be an actual viable question if you would post a [mcve]. `<map>`s are position specific HTML has important info needed to assess your problem, and if you are going to use JavaScript that would be necessary as well. Moreover, tascoshy has a point a CSS grid would be a better choice, in fact almost anything would be a better alternative than a `<map>` .

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will support CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Style up the boxes inside boxes to resemble a calculator and script up a solution using [keyup](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-keyup) events.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you can definitely make clickable elements that execute JS over an image - using an image map.

You can looking at this [W3 example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_map2) , and then just try adding in your own onClick event to one of the elements. Maybe trying pasting this into the link above

```
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" onClick="console.log('test')">
</map>
```

Alternatively, you could just actually overlay an html element (like a button) over the image.

With that being said, if you want even the faintest amount of responsiveness to your UI (i.e. text showing the numbers you typed in or button animation). You really shouldn't use an image with an imageMap. You are much better off just designing the buttons and calculator yourself using HTML. So assuming you're trying to build a calculator app, I wouldn't use an imagemap.